# Select box in a ForeignObject within an svg within an svg doesn't repaint/update if it has a dropshadow in d3.js

Tags: html, google-chrome, d3.js, svg, safari

**Problem**

I am creating some svg icons and a select box in a ForeignObject to act on the timeline of a graph. The svg contains preset date ranges to set the graph to. While working on this, I found that in some browsers, changing the select box would not update the `<option>` correctly. You would change the svg, but the contents would not change until some mouse events occured.

My HTML structure is like this:

```
body
  svg
    defs
    svg
       g icon
         svg
       g icon
         svg
       g icon
         svg
       g icon
         svg
       g icon
         svg
       foreignObject
         selectbox
```

**How to Reproduce**

I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2frbzuxo/1/

**Behaviour**

- In Chrome/Chromium/Brave, when you change the select box, it does not update until a mouse event (mouseleave or mouseover) is triggered which updates the icon `path` element.
- In safari, when you change the select box, you have to **click** the icons, moving the mouse over them does not update the select box
- Using Konqueror or Falkon or Firefox 69 Quantum, everything works as expected.

Tested on 64-bit Gentoo Linux and Mac OS X 10.14.6 Sierra platforms, d3.js version 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround / Solution**

The reason this issue is occuring is because Chrome-based browsers and Safari do not properly handle the dropshadow filter that I applied to the select box. Somehow they do not render  or repaint correctly. Removing the dropshadow `filter` in the `svg` element will properly update the `select` button when the option is changed.

```html
<svg class="buttons" filter="url(#svg-dropshadow)" fill="url(#svg-gradient)" x="0"><rect fill="white" stroke="rgba(232, 232, 232, 0.6)" width="100" height="24">
```

becomes

```html
<svg class="buttons" fill="url(#svg-gradient)" x="0"><rect fill="white" stroke="rgba(232, 232, 232, 0.6)" width="100" height="24">
```

I've filed a report with Chrome and Safari browsers so hopefully this issue will be resolved soon.